# Want powershell to ask for Computer Name

Tags: powershell

I am renaming computers with powershell after imaging, and would like the script to ask me for the new computer name, so I don't have to edit the script every time. Here is what I have:

```
Rename-Computer -NewName ComputerNameHere -LocalCredential Administrator
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`Read-Host`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176935.aspx) cmdlet:

```
$name = Read-Host 'New Computer Name'
Rename-Computer -NewName $name -LocalCredential Administrator
```